# How can I import specific blueprint components into Compass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I am able to load the entire blueprint css framework into my project with the following code in screen.scss:

```
@import "compass";
@import "blueprint";
@include blueprint;
```

However, I would only like to include specific components, such as "blueprint/grid" and "blueprint/buttons":

```
@import "compass";
@import "blueprint/grid";
@import "blueprint/buttons";
@include blueprint;
```

When I try to import just those pieces, I get the following error:

```
error resources/sass/screen.scss (Line 12: Undefined mixin 'blueprint'.)
```

Does anyone know how to include parts of blueprint, but not everything?

Answer (score 1):

The blueprint mixin is located in the root stylesheet. Meaning what you did is all correct, but you still need to do @import "blueprint" to get the main mixin.

```
@import "compass";
@import "blueprint";
@import "blueprint/grid";
@import "blueprint/buttons";
@include blueprint;
```